# How to POST some properties using an AJAX array?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I want to POST my array data through AJAX posting method.
For getting those values in an array, I have used a  ViewModel.
My controller code is as::

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SavePlaylist(List<ItemEditViewModel> data, long playlistid, List<long> deleted, string Title)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        var pc = new PlaylistContent();
    }

    return Playlist(playlistid);
}
```

I have used my AJAX posting as ::

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: { data: data , playlistid: parseInt(playlistid) },
    traditional: true,
    url: 'SavePlaylist',
    success: function (data) {
        search(playlistid,"Playlist");
        alert("Playlist saved successfully!!");
    }
})
```

Here my data `POST`ed in the form as::

```
data:[object object]
data:[object object]
data:[object object]

Playlistid:5
```

Its not matching the ViewModel made as:

```
public class ItemEditViewModel
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public long MetaID { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get all the values `POST`ed using this kind of array?

Comment: Can you show the structure of your `POST` `data` object? It's members and what not?

Comment: I have shown above the structure of data